# Greenplum \ postgresql COPY: extra data after last expected column

Tags: c#, postgresql, greenplum

I'm working on a Greenplum DB 4.3 project which is using PostgreSQL version 8.2. I am trying to import data with STDIN using COPY.

The data contains backslashes, commas, pipes and anything else you can think of. These values cannot be altered.

Below is an example of the data:

1000,"A",0,"","LKP","","L",0,"U","None|Local copy",

1001,"B",0,"","LIT","","L",0,"U","[1005]\source\",

The command which I am using:

(psql)
\copy cdr.wf_step_props_ist from '/home/gpadmin/temp.csv' CSV FILL MISSING FIELDS DELIMITER ',' NEWLINE 'CRLF' QUOTE '"'

(c#)
COPY cdr.WF_STEP_PROPS_IST (STEP_ID,PARAM_CODE,OCCUR_NO,VALUE_FILE,EVAL_TYPE,DPC_FAILURE_MSG,DPC_PRIORITY,DPC_SEQ,VALUE_STATE,PARAM_VALUE) FROM STDIN CSV NEWLINE 'CRLF' QUOTE '\"' NULL ' ' DELIMITER ',' FILL MISSING FIELDS

But I keep getting this error:

> ERROR:  extra data after last expected column  (seg11 sdw3:40003
>   pid=14935) CONTEXT:  COPY wf_step_props_ist, line 1:
>   "10003,"FCExtConn",0,"","LKP","","L",0,"U","None|Local copy",
>   10003,"FCInput",0,"","LIT","","L",0,"U"..."

I attempted this from C# & PSQL CLI on Ubuntu (using COPY with CSV file) and the result is the same.

The answers I have found on stackoverflow don't provide a solution to this problem. Is there anyone who could explain to me why this does not work?

Thanks

Comment: you have 10 columns but your csv file has 11.. the last comma is superfluous.

Comment: Why are you loading data with COPY into Greenplum rather than gpload or External Tables with gpfdist?  gpload is much, much faster and is easily configurable.

Comment: I am attempting a single means to transfer data which caters for Greenplum AND Postgres 9+.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

i have executed this with `PostgreSQL 9.4.10` and its working:

```
copy cdr.wf_step_props_ist FROM STDIN CSV DELIMITER ',' QUOTE ''''; < your_file.csv
```

your data:

> 1000,"A",0,"","LKP","","L",0,"U","None|Local copy"
>
> 1001,"B",0,"","LIT","","L",0,"U","[1005]\source\"

Also look at this link for more info about [copy in PostgreSQL 8.2](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-copy.html)

Comment: I know it works in newer versions of Postgres. It doesn't work in Greenplum.

Comment: `FILL MISSING FIELDS` and  `NEWLINE 'CRLF'` aren't in copy docs. And the error output also says you have more columns than expected. Remove those commas at the end of the line and avoid not supported copy parameters. And try again with `psql`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback

Comment: COPY supports NEWLINE and FILL MISSING FIELDS

Comment: I have spoken from PostgreSQL server 8 2